# Redirect WordPress subdomain to Laravel main site

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I've have 2 sites, a Laravel/Vuejs application running on my main domain (e.g. `website.com`) and a simple WordPress blog on a subdomain (e.g. `blog.website.com`). I don't want to place my WordPress blog as a subfolder in my public folder of my Laravel app, but I want to keep both sites separate like they are now.

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect or show the contents of my WordPress blog on a '/blog' url on my Laravel application. `website.com/blog` should get the contents of `blog.website.com` and `blog.website.com` should redirect to `website.com/blog`.

Below you can find the redirect in my `.htaccess` file, rewriting my `blog.website.com` to `website.com/blog`, which works like a charm! My subdomain redirects to my Laravel application with a trailing '/blog'.

```
//
// .htaccess
//

# Rewrite subdomain to main url.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.website.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now this is where the tricky part starts. My Laravel application displays a Vuejs (with Vue Router) application, with my `web.php` forcing any route (except 'api' or 'blog') to return the welcome view, containing my Vuejs assets (CSS, JS, etc). I've also added a '/blog' exception to my `web.php` file, in order to redirect visitors when they visit the blog page as you can see in my code below:

```
//
// web.php
//

Route::get('/{any?}', function (){
  return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api|blog).*$');

Route::get('/blog', function () {
  return redirect('https://blog.website.com/');
});
```

Everything bundled up together results as expected in the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error, or an infinite redirect loop. Visiting `blog.website.com` results into a url rewrite to `website.com/blog`, which in it's turn redirects 'back' to `blog.website.com`.

Removing the `https://blog.website.com/` redirect from the `web.php` file results in Laravels' default 404 page not found. So, how could I tackle this redirect issue keeping my Laravel and WordPress environment separate from each other?

**EDIT:**

As Kamlesh Paul suggested, I've tried editing my `nginx.conf` file by adding the server block inside of the http block:

```
//
// /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
//

http {
    ...
    server {
        server_name blog.website.com;
        return 301 https://www.website.com/blog$request_uri;
    }
}
```

After removing all other possible solutions (`.htaccess` and `web.php` changes) and a server/nginx restart nothing happens.

Comment: it is on sharedhost or vps .?

Comment: Hi Kamlesh Paul, both are hosted on a VPS!

Comment: did you created config for subdomain .? it is nginx or apache2

Comment: in `Route::get('/blog', function () {` shouln't you show your blog? instead of redirecting to the old blog? meaning, `return view('welcome');` or `return view('blog-index');` or something like that

Comment: `/blog` should show the contents of the `blog.website.com` subdomain.

Comment: @PabloMartinez I don't have a view for my blog because my blog is an entirely separate WordPress site on a subdomain.

Comment: @KamleshPaul it's nginx!

Comment: then you need to create 2 config file one for `blog` and one for `laravel`

Comment: Not sure on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite trying several solutions from the comments, I've managed to solve my question by using a symlink!

Logged into my server I've navigated to the public folder of my Laravel application (the below folder structure may vary on different OS).

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/public
```

Using the following code I've created a `symlink` or `symbolic link` that acts (more-or-less) as a shortcut to my subdomain.

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/website.com/blog.website.com/ blog
```

This code creates a `blog` folder in the `public` folder of my Laravel application and links it to the root folder of my WordPress blog.

Next, I've removed the redirect to the blog subdomain in my `web.php`, which now looks like the following:

```
//
// web.php
//

Route::get('/{any?}', function (){
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api|blog).*$');
```

Excluding my Laravels' application url with a trailing `/blog` from serving a specific view, allows the Laravel application to fallback on retrieving the `blog` folder in the `public` folder. Since the `blog` folder is linked to my subdomain, the WordPress blog is shown!

This allowed me to log into my WordPress dashboard in order to change my blogs' site-url and home address in the General settings from `https://blog.website.com` to `https://website.com/blog`. This also fixes/implements the new URL structure to all the post types (posts, pages, etc). If this doesn't fix it for you just visit the 'Permalinks' page to automatically flush all URL's (even though it looks like nothing has happend).

The final step was to create a redirect for any direct traffic visiting the old `blog.website.com` url, which I've added to my `.htaccess` file in the following way:

```
//
// .htaccess
//

# Rewrite subdomain to main url.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.website.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```